# [Errno 10054], selenium chromedriver crashing each time

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Every time I open up Chrome driver in my python script, it says "chromedriver.exe has stopped working" and crashes my script with the error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

I read the other forum posts on this error, but I'm very new to this and a lot of it was jargon that I didn't understand.  One said something about graceful termination, and one guy said "running the request again" solved his issue, but I have no idea how to do that.  Can someone explain to me in more detail how to fix this?

Comment: try with the latest chrome webdriver. may be the compatibility issue. what's your selenium, chrome, and chrome driver versions?

Comment: What version of selenium and chrome driver are you using??

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.  It was a compatibility error.  Just needed to downloaded the latest chrome driver version and it worked.